# What is the word for a good work?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-requests

I am helping a charity and I need to invite my friends to join in. We're not asking for any money or valuables but just their time for some feedback on few questions.

I am struggling at the opening line of the invitation message—what I want to say is that "I need your help in this great work / noble work" but it just doesn't sound that impressive/catchy.

Jihad or movement both describe something too big to describe "answering a few questions."

Please note that it is for non-native English speakers.

Comment: I would look at this question: [what's the opposite word for 'sin'](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10991/whats-the-opposite-word-for-sin). About the best you can do is "I performed a good/virtuous/righteous/moral/meritorious  act/deed."

Comment: thx checking tht ques - also - what is a noble cause?

Comment: If it is for non-native English speakers, why do you need an English word?

Comment: @KitFox i didn't say non-english speaking

Comment: I would look no further than a dictionary: [noble](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/noble) [cause](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cause). Again, there's not a single word that does what you want. Since this is for non-native English speakers, you may as well use the simplest, most direct choice of words. If you're really looking for a **single word**, you could try *jihad* or *movement*, but these have all kinds of other connotations and don't work well for your stated purpose.

Comment: @Zairja jihad/movement too 'big' thx

Comment: @HappyApe I think KitFox is referring to "Please note that it is for non-native english speakers." in your question

Comment: @jim dear jim I do understand but I have asked for an english word kitfox said "why do you need an English word?"

Comment: And you said [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/79450/what-is-the-word-for-a-good-work#comment156859_79450)

Comment: @HappyApe *endeavor*, *undertaking*, *task*... If these words are too big, then stick with "good/great work". It doesn't need to be "catchy" or "impressive" to be effective. Sometimes a clear, simple, direct message is all you  need, *especially for people who may not know much English*.

Comment: Yes, I am confused. If you are addressing non-native English speakers, why are you using English? If you use your native language, then you wouldn't have to translate. That's all I meant.

Comment: Why not just call it service?

Comment: Sorry not a service - I am thinking about 'endeavour'

Comment: Requests to correct/rewrite your text are off topic, see [faq]. Voting to close OT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would look at this question: [what's the opposite word for 'sin'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10991/whats-the-opposite-word-for-sin). About the best you can do is "I performed a good/virtuous/righteous/moral/meritorious act/deed."

Again, there's not a single word that does what you want. Since this is for non-native English speakers, you may as well use the simplest, most direct choice of words. If you're really looking for a single word, you could try *jihad* or *movement*, but these have all kinds of other connotations and don't work well for your stated purpose

*Endeavor*, *undertaking*, *task*. . . If these words are too big, then stick with "good/great work". It doesn't need to be "catchy" or "impressive" to be effective. Sometimes a clear, simple, direct message is all you need, especially for people who may not know much English.

If you really need some buzzword or catchphrase to make an impact, consider hiring a PR firm!

Comment: I'm not sure how "jihad" would come across to your intended audience, but to most people "jihad" means "religion-inspired war". Regardless of what the term really means to Moslems, that's the connotation. If you're trying to change that perception, I'd consider whether an appeal for a non-violent and/or non-Islamic charity is the best place to do that.

Comment: @Jay Agreed, I just had to throw it out there. Additionally, in emails I get for "calls to action" (i.e. donate) I see wording like this: "The *struggle* for reproductive rights is ongoing. Your *involvement* is needed on many issues. *Get active* and make your voice heard by joining..." The word choice definitely gives off a political vibe, but it suits its purpose since politics are involved here. I think how to frame a "good deed" is really determined by your audience.

Comment: I chose "good deed".

Answer (score 8):

I don't know a single English word that isn't hopelessly archaic. Hebrew/Yiddish has *mitzvah*, if your fellow-primates are in the Jewish community.

Otherwise I'd go with "I need your contribution to this *effort*". Contributing to an *effort* feels gratifyingly strenuous, out of all proportion to the actual energy expended.

Comment: Similar to how we buy something for $9.99 (look at the savings) but donate $10.00 (see how generous I am). ;)

Comment: thanks I like that but as I had already chosen "good deed" before your answer. +1

Comment: @HappyApe No sweat, and I appreciate your appreciation.

Answer (score 2):

We tend to play greatness down in the UK - it may be a national failing, but results in descriptors such as *great endeavour* or *noble work* sounding rather pompous or naive. *Jihad* and *crusade* can sound very threatening. We'd probably stick with *(very) worthwhile project*.

Comment: I thought *pompous* exactly.

Answer (score 2):

"Altruistic" is a good word to use as it suggests a selfless act and avoids the moral/political/religious tone of some of the other suggestions here.

Answer (score 1):

Could you say, "Please join me in this philanthropic opportunity."

[*Philanthropic*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/philanthropic) is defined as:

> showing concern for humanity, esp by performing charitable actions, donating money, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I'd stick with "good work", "great work", "noble work", "good cause", "important work", etc.

I don't know your audience, but in general, I'd be cautious about trying too hard to sound profound and important. If you try to sound profound and don't get it quite right, you often end up sounding pretentious or just plain silly.

Answer (score 0):

First, of all, you are amazing! Doing volunteer work for a nonprofit organization is truly a noble thing to do. Also, you did well in acknowledging someone's effort to make this world a better place to live in especially for future generations to come.

I think when you want to use the phrase "Good work".

You may have to determine first to whom are you going to say it, what is his or her religious and cultural background. You may then use meaningful phrases that he or she can relate to using the kind of terms used in their dialects. Since I am from the Philippines, instead of saying the phrase "Good job!" we often say "Magaling!" It means the same but it feels more meaningful as this word is akin to him and his roots. Creativity, meaning, and transforming the lives of others is a great thing. Keep it up!